# Mute iOS microphone input with ReactNative

Tags: objective-c, react-native, agora.io

I am using [Agora's ReactNative library](https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora) for a group calling project, I need the user to be able to mute/unmute his phone microphone. Currently there is only a function to `muteLocalAudioStream` which does mute the whole stream, that includes the background sounds, as the streamer can add background sound to the call.

For Android I managed to mute/unmute the microphone with the below hack:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void muteMic(){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        if (audioManager.isMicrophoneMute() == false) {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);

        } else {
            audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
        }
    }
```

However, I couldn't do it for iOS, I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I don't know if this can help you but there's a library [react-native-incall-manager](https://github.com/zxcpoiu/react-native-incall-manager) to handle actions during a video/audio call. It gives you the possibility to mute/unmute microphone without writing any native code. Hope this help you, good luck

Comment: Thank you, but look how funny is the function of muting the mic: `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setMicrophoneMute:(BOOL)enable) { NSLog(@"RNInCallManager.setMicrophoneMute(): ios doesn't support setMicrophoneMute()"); }` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change recording level with a call to

```js
// volume: [0,100]
RtcEngine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(volume)
```